# In Pokemon Go, how exactly are you rewarded Defender Bonus?

Tags: pokemon-go

It seems that once I occupy a gym, and claim the Defender Bonus, then during the day, if I occupy two more gyms, there is no way to claim more Defender Bonus.

So how exactly do you get Defender Bonus?

So far I have some observations:

1. As long as you never claim Defender Bonus within the past 21 hours, you can claim it.
2. Once you claim it, you have to wait 21 hours to claim any Defender Bonus again, even if you conquer or go in more gyms.
3. When you claim Defender Bonus, the number of gyms you are in at that time determines how much stardust and Pokecoins you get (which is 500 stardust + 10 Pokecoins) x NumberOfGymAtTheTimeOfClaim)
4. In other words, if you claim it when you are in one gym, and you go into 5 more gyms, but 21 hours later, you are only in two gyms now, then if you claim at that time, you can claim Defender Bonus for two gyms only.
5. So naturally, it is better to claim it at the point in time, when simultaneously, you are in the maximum number of gyms.
6. It doesn't matter whether you bring the Prestige to 0 and kick out every other Pokemon and go in a gym, or whether you just "pass by" and find an empty slot to go in. It count as 1 gym.
7. Once a gym is emptied out, there are 3 slots for Pokemon (of the same team) to go in.
8. If another person can "sneak in" and two other persons of the same team also add themselves immediately, now you have to bring down the Prestige to 0 for a gym with 3 Pokemons in it. So you'd better choose which Pokemon you want to go in ahead of time and do it fast. (and revive it fast if it died in the fight. But maybe you don't have to restore its health to the max -- I am not sure yet).
9. Update: I think I heard the maximum number of gym you can be in or rewarded for, is 10, and Defender Bonus will double every time you are in one more gym... meaning after 9 more gyms, it is multiply by 512... but it must be too good to be true.

Don't know if this is correct?

Comment: Sounds like you're over-thinking the defender bonus.

Comment: Sounds like you answered your own question too.

Comment: Also, side note on your edit: a Pokemon must be at full HP to be put into a gym.

Comment: Where did the 512 come from? Like @Ellesedil said, you are overthinking this. The system is pretty straightforward and I've described exactly how the Defender bonus rewards you in my answer...

Comment: There's a number (n) in the Defender Bonus shield, that's how much stardust/coins you will get (n x 500/10), i.e. how many gyms have your Pokemon in them at that time

Comment: @Ellesedil well the question itself isn't a duplicate, but the answer to the other question covers this question as well, since it goes in depth.

Comment: the number 512 comes from, if you multiply 2 by 9 times... which is 2 to the power 9, then it is 512

Comment: Uh, okay. Well, what you heard about the reward doubling for every gym is absolutely false. I don't know if the maximum is 10 gyms, as I've never been able to get that many before cashing in, but it's a constant increase, not exponential. That would completely negate the incentive to spend money on the game and be a horrible business model for Niantic.

Comment: Also, just to finally address your numbered points: 1-3 accurately describe and pretty much completely encompass how the defender bonus works (meaning you answered your own question), 4-6 describe the best way to maximize rewards, 7 and 8 aren't related to your question, and 9 is completely false.

Comment: @Vemonus hm... I do find 10 Pokecoins to be quite little... it is like 10 cents... it will take 100 days to earn $9.99... or rather... $9.99 gets you 1200 Pokecoins... so it will take you 4 months if you earn 10 Pokecoins per day... but if you really can occupy 10 gyms, then it takes only 12 days

Comment: I like your username ;)

Answer (score 3):

You are allowed to claim a Defender bonus once every 21 hours. The Defender bonus is linked to you, not the gyms you occupy. Once you are eligible, you can claim a Defender bonus. Once you claim it, a 21 hour countdown timer starts and you will not be able to collect a Defender bonus again until that timer ends.

The breakdown of the Defender bonus is as follows:

For every gym you occupy **at the time you cash in your bonus**, you receive:

1. 500 stardust
2. 10 Pokécoins

This is the only way to get Pokécoins without spending real-life money.

Comment: so at first I thought it is "per gym"... in order words, "You are allowed to claim a Defender bonus once every 21 hours" [per each gym]... but looks like it is "per the number of gyms you are in at the time"

Comment: Yes, that's what I said in my answer. If you try to take over 4 gyms before you cash in but one is kicked out before you cash in, then you'll only get the bonus for the 3 you occupy when you cash in.

Comment: aha... when it is said in so short sentence, I think it sums it up, but without knowing how it works, I think I needed some more explanation.  For example, I even thought at first you can claim it, but you have to be in the gym for at least 21 hours for the Defend Bonus to be rewarded... but it turns out you can be in it for 20 seconds and you will be rewarded if you claim it

Comment: @太極者無極而生 Well, I'm glad you understand now.